# How to specify multiple roles of a contributor on Zenodo

Tags: zenodo

I am preparing a data deposit for Zenodo, in which most contributors fulfilled multiple roles.

Do I really have to add each contributor multiple times, or is there a different way of adding multiple roles to a single contributor?

Answer (score 0):

It really seems that at the moment specifying each contributor once for each role is the only way of doing this.